# Boundary the closure is included in the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Id like to show that for a subset $S$ of a $\mathbb{R}^2$, the following two things hold:

1. $\text{bd}(\text{int}(S)) \subseteq \text{bd}(S)$
2. $\text{bd}(\text{cl}(S)) \subseteq \text{bd}(S)$

This is what I need to prove that if $S$ is reimann measurable, then so are it's interior and its closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in any metric space $(X,d)$.

Fix $x\in \partial  (\text{int}(S))$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption, there are points $y\in \text{int}(S)$ and $z\not\in\text{int}(S)$ such that  $d(x,y),d(x,z)<\varepsilon$. Note  that $y\in S$. Since $z\not\in\text{int}(S)$, there is some $p\in X\setminus  S$ such that $d(z,p)<\varepsilon-d(x,z)$. By the triangle inequality, $d(p,x)<\varepsilon$. This shows that $x\in\partial S$.

The other case is very similar. Try giving it a shot. Still, here's a full solution:

> Fix $x\in\partial(\text{cl}(S))$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption, there are points $y\in \text{cl}(S)$ and $z\not\in\text{cl}(S)$ such that  $d(x,y),d(x,z)<\varepsilon$.. Since $z\not \in \text{cl}(S)$, we obviously have $z\not\in S$. Now, $y\in \text{cl}(S)$, so there is some $p\in S$ such that $d(p,y)<\varepsilon-d(x,y)$. Again, the triangle inequality yields $d(x,p)<\varepsilon$. This shows that $x\in\partial S$.

Comment: Does this work for arbitrary topological spaces?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett My intuition says no, but I don't have an example off the top of my head. Something with horrible separation properties might work.